# #Repeating a column in a data set

Tags: r

I have a data set of this form:

```
ID   child1  child2  child3
1     ADE      SOLA     BIMPE
2    TUNDE     BYRA     FUNMY
```

And I want this output

```
1D   child
 1   ADE
 1   SOLA
 1   BIMPE
 2   TUNDE
2    BYRA
2    FUNMY
```

Please how do I write a code in R to obtain that output

Comment: what did you try? Or think that might work?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `reshape2` package with `melt`

Answer (score 0):

```
data <- data.frame( 
  ID = 1:2, 
  child1 = c("ADE", "TUNDE"), 
  child2 = c("SOLA", "BYRA"), 
  child3 = c("BIMPE", "FUNMY"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

melt(data, id.vars = "ID", value.name = "child")
  ID variable child
1  1   child1   ADE
2  2   child1 TUNDE
3  1   child2  SOLA
4  2   child2  BYRA
5  1   child3 BIMPE
6  2   child3 FUNMY
```